# Is there a way to take a screenshot of the screen of android/ios device without active user action?

Tags: android, ios, permissions, screenshot, policy

I'm beginner in mobile development, and I have a question:
"Whether the device can take screenshots of the screen of an open application without active user action, if the user has allowed this action in advance?"

The screenshot data will not be sent anywhere, but will be processed by the application itself and deleted from the phone’s memory.

Looking for any thoghts :)

I find out that ios dont allow this type of action without active sction from the user. What about Android ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#takeScreenshot(int,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.TakeScreenshotCallback)

Comment: IOS application can take the current screen as an image and you can save it to disk if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak on iOS, but for Android, the following applies:

If you only want to capture the screen of your own application or a part of it, you can take a `View` and convert it to a Bitmap which is an image that you then can process directly or do whatever you wish with it.

The method for that would be `View.drawToBitmap()`

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#drawtobitmap) is a link to the documentation.